# how to get distinct value while using apply.join in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am joining different values from a dataset into one column in Pandas Dataframe, however there are lots of duplication, how can I get rid of them without deleting any row?:
example:

```
newCol
------
123,456,129,123,123
237,438,365,432,438
```

using df.newCol.drop_duplicates() removes the entire rows but I want the result to be:

```
newCol
------
123,456,129
237,438,365,432
```

...

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need first `split`, apply `set` and then `join`:

```
df.newCol = df.newCol.apply(lambda x: ','.join(set(str(x).split(','))))
print (df)
            newCol
0      129,123,456
1  432,365,438,237
```

---

But you can apply `set` in `join` before:

```
print (df)
     0    1    2    3    4
0  123  456  129  123  123
1  237  438  365  432  438

df = df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(set(x.astype(str))), axis=1)
print (df)
0        129,123,456
1    432,365,438,237
dtype: object
```

Or [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html):

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: ','.join((x.astype(str)).unique()), axis=1)
print (df)
0        123,456,129
1    237,438,365,432
dtype: object
```

Comment: thank you for your solution, I forgot to mention that the data is combination of integers and strings.,..i get this error when i use your solution: "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'"...excuse me for my basic questions i'm new to python

Comment: now i get this error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'astype'

Comment: ok it is working, I had a dropna() which caused the issue...thank you so much for quick respond :)